# functions inside $.each execute only for first JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, iteration, each

I have some JSON e.g

```
Levels = {
    "1" : {
        "level"   : 1,
        "name"    : "blah blah",
        "TTtitle" : "blah blah blah blah"
    },
    "2" : {
        "level"   : 2,
        "name"    : "blah blah",
        "TTtitle" : "blah blah blah blah"
    }
};
```

when I declare a function inside an each loop it only executes on the first one e.g

```
var addIcons;    
$.each(Levels, function(key, value){
       v = value,
       addIcons = function(){                                               
         $(
           '<li class="icon' + key + '">'+                                              
           '<a class="Tip" href="#' + key + '" title="' + v.TTtitle +'"></a>'+
           '</li>'
          ).appendTo('ul');                                     
       }
    });
addIcons();
```

Is it not a good idea to declare functions inside loops?

How do I get the function to fire for each "Level"?

***This is just an example of some code I was testing as I was using 5 seperate each loops within separate functions and was looking for a way only to iterate through the JSON once and set the functions.***

Comment: current scenario can be solved as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RjdSt/1/

Comment: but if you can recreate the real case in the fiddle we might be able to help you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
$.each(Levels, function(key, value){
    var v = value;
    $('<li class="icon' + key + '">' +                                              
      '<a class="Tip" href="#' + key + '" title="' + v.TTtitle + '">t</a>' +
      '</li>').appendTo('ul');                                     
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RjdSt/)

But if you want to create a list of functions and execute them later then try

```
var addIcons = [];    
$.each(Levels, function(key, value){
    var v = value;

    addIcons.push(function(){                                               
        $(
            '<li class="icon' + key + '">'+                                              
            '<a class="Tip" href="#' + key + '" title="' + v.TTtitle +'"></a>'+
            '</li>'
        ).appendTo('ul');                                     
    })
});

$.each(addIcons, function(idx, fn){
    fn();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b7WQR/)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can write as follows
$.each(Levels, function(key, value){
   v = value,
     $('ul').append(
       '<li class="icon' + key + '">'+                                              
       '<a class="Tip" href="#' + key + '" title="' + v.TTtitle +'"></a>'+
       '</li>'
      );                                     
});
```